# Docker Mount an entire mounted host partition as a data volume

Tags: linux, docker

My system has two partitions:

5G main partition where Ubuntu is installed
100G side partition at /mnt/data that I'd like to use for Docker container as storage

for testing i was create also directory /tmp/mnt
Also I put  test file in both

```
touch /tmp/mnt/file
touch /mnt/data/file
```

then I start docker images

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -v /tmp/mnt:/var/data imagename bash
sudo docker run -it --rm -v /mnt/data:/var/data imagename bash
```

in image with /tmp/mnt I see /var/data/file, but in image with /mnt/data not

both images show same outout for df -h /var/data

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.1G  2.7G  66% /var/data
```

Does it possible to mount separate partition into docker?

Comment: This is more a linux question - the behavior would probably the same for normal mount operations accross partitions. My assumption is your /mnt is on a different partition. You might want to check this.

Comment: Hi @Alexandar, Did you find a solution for this, by any chance?